# SQL Server - Stored procedures slow vs "Giant" script

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a large number of stored procedures (about 200) that need to be executed sequentially. Ideally I wanted to create a single "master" stored procedure that would execute each of the individual stored procedures one after another.

However, when I execute the master stored procedure it consistently freezes after running a long time. That being said, if I take all the SQL code from the 200 individual stored procedures and create one giant SQL script file, it runs without any issue.

The SQL code queries separate tables and inserts a subset of the data into a master "summary" table.

Any ideas why this would happen? Is there something about stored procedures that take more memory? I would prefer to keep everything in stored procedures so we could manage security and updates easier.

Comment: Are any of the stored procedures creating, modifying or deleting any other stored procedures?  What about other object types?

Comment: No. The stored procedures do not modify other stored procedures. They query other tables and insert a subset of that data into a separate aggregate table.

Comment: Then you should take a look at the output of `sp_lock` when the master sproc freezes.  What does it show?

Comment: Just a followup .. I tried adding `WITH RECOMPILE` when calling the stored procedure but I still have the same slowdown issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas why this would happen?

Compilation.

The master script likely is compiled batch by batch using the statistics valid at this point.

The SP will be compiled once at start, and if the statistics change during the run - as is typial for a sequence of loads - there you go. Especially if the statistical change is significant during processing. Basically the stats at teh beginning - when things are compiled - are totally off compared to the runtime stats for some tables.

There is a recompile option that you can se tin the individual statements to avoid this.

Comment: But the big SP is the one that works.  The master script is the one that locks up.

Comment: This i not what you say. Let me quote: However, when I execute the master stored procedure it consistently freezes after running a long time. That being said, if I take all the SQL code from the 200 individual stored procedures and create one giant SQL script file, it runs without any issue.

Comment: I am not the OP, but what you quote is the same as what I said above: the master script/sproc freezes, the big script/sproc works.  Note that posters of SQL questions frequently make a poor distinction between scripts and sprocs (an Oracle influence I suspect).  The identifying distinction between the two that I see is "master" (calls others) vs. "big" (all together).

Comment: I am the OP so just to clarify .. the master stored procedure is the one locking up. The "Giant" script that contains all of the code in the stored procedures is the one that executes without issue.

Comment: Then my assumption stands. The SP is combiled once, with the statistics valid at the start.

Comment: So it sounds like a should recompile the individual stored procedures and performance should be increased?

Comment: @TomTom, No.  In any "Master" script or sproc, the called sprocs are *NOT* compiled at the beginning of the Master invocation.  They are complied when they are called (caching aside).

Comment: Actually you can put an option ercombile in the critical sql statements ;) http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/