# Regular Expressions to remove DDL language from stored procedures

Tags: regex, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a large number of stored procedures that I have scripted to a single file. I now need to remove all the DDL language in this large file so I can run the file as one script.

My thought was to use regular expressions to match the DDL code and remove it. So I would like to match and such text as ..

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[XXXXXX]    Script Date: 4/25/2014 2:06:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[XXXXXX]  
    (@Client int = Null)

AS
BEGIN
```

and replace is within an empty string. How would I go about matching the start and end of the text and then removing everything in between? Also, would it be possible to have several different "matches" so that different section could be removed? I was planning on using an advanced text editor that supports regular expresssions such as Notepad++, EditPad, or UltraEdit to do the actual editing.

Comment: I have the same but instead I use the sqlcmd.exe and run that from my code. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Could you explain further? How does sqlcmd.exe help you accomplish the removal of the DDL?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand why you want to remove the ddl. I have a similar script that I use to keep my schema up to date. Before each ddl statement I check for the existence of the object and delete the sp or don't create the table or what ever is the best action. Obviously you cannot run the code with GO from ado.net so I use sqlcmd.exe to load and run the script if I wish to run the file programatically, eg) test setup and during deployment

Comment: For the why? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300598/export-the-functionality-of-many-stored-procedures-to-script

Comment: could it be as simple as looking for the text between BEGIN and END? Extract this code to a new file and 'leave' the ddl behind?

Comment: That would work but I am unsure how to do so. I figured a RegEx would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression seemed to work.

`\bGO(.*?)AS\b`

Essentially it matched all the DDL code, with the exception of

`BEGIN`,`END`, and `USE` statements

I then replaced all the matched text with an empty string. The key was the use of the `?` which tells the regular expression engine to be "lazy" and not "greedy" in it's matching. This allows the matching to stop after it encounters the `AS` keyword.

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) was a big help to me in figuring this out.

Comment: In UltraEdit the **Perl regular expression** search string must be `(?s)\bGO(.*?)AS\b`. `(?s)` at beginning of the search string is a flag which lets `.` match also carriage return and line-feed. The default behavior for `.` in UltraEdit is matching any character except line terminating characters.

Comment: That is a good point. I used Notepad++ but I did need to enable the option to allow the `.` match carriage return and line feed.

Comment: `[\s\S]` instead of `.` is a general solution to match **any** character including line terminating characters as this character class expression matches all whitespace characters **and** all non whitespace characters. Therefore it is also possible to use `\bGO([\s\S]*?)AS\b` as search string.

Answer (score 1):

a possible regex could be 
    (?<=BEGIN)(.|\n)*(?=EN\D)

this should return a match for each procedure body

Comment: The RegEx works great but is selecting the text I want to preserve. Is there a way to select all other text instead of what the RegEx matches? I mention this because I don't know how to pull the selected text out and save it into a file or to the clipboard. While if I can select the text "NOT MATCHING" the RegEx I can just delete it.

Comment: In UltraEdit the **Perl regular expression** search string `(?s)(?<=\bEND\b).*?(?=\bBEGIN\b)` matches all text between **END** and **BEGIN**. The replace string must be `\r\n` (DOS/Windows file) or just `\n` (Unix file). Please note that a DDL code at top or bottom of the file is not removed by this search string as there is no **END** at top and no **BEGIN** at end.